# How to receive postback using Express and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a server written in Express that interfaces with an application written in Angular on the client.

My Express server is receiving a post from a third-party service to a route which will perform business logic, and then here is where I am a little uncertain about the best path forward.

After receiving the post variables, I want to redirect the request to an Angular route, but I want to make those received post variables available to the route as well.

Somehow, I want to be able to mix the res.json() and res.redirect() method, but I'm pretty sure they both end the response.

What would be a logical way to structure this?

**Update:** To expand on the issue, imagine I have a route called /receivetransaction which receives some postback variables, including transaction ID, amount etc. I want to perform business logic (save to a database), and then redirect the user to /thankyou (an angular route) but have them be able to access that data that was just received in the postback.

It looks like maybe my best option would be to save to the database, and then send the transaction-id as JSON to the angular view, which will then hit the database and pull the info. A little inefficient though (not really a big deal) but I would hope there would be another way around it.

Comment: You have to pick one or the other, you can't do both.

Comment: "After receiving the post variables, I want to redirect the request to an Angular route" -- can you expand on what you mean here

Comment: I don't think you can post to angular.  Angular is not meant to handle server requests.  It can process a 'post to' or 'get to' request, however it can't receive post requests.  You would have to save the data that you are getting and create a service for angular to retrieve that data.

Comment: I've updated the question and yes Sohrab I think I am coming to the same conclusion that you have posted.

Comment: So the redirect has to be a proper HTTP redirect (not something internal in Express), because you want to make the client go to /thankyou. This means that you'll have two requests (POST then a GET) on the server. The only way to relate these two is either to use a session (keep the state on the server), or as you said, let the client maintain the state via the id you send. The latter seems cleaner and may even be more efficient (even if you hit the DB twice, you wouldn't need to worry about maintaining extra data in the session for each request pair, etc.)

Comment: I've added an answer with the route (no pun intended ;) ) I've decided to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've decided to do is the following:

After the express route receives the postback variables, it performs the business logic (specifically saving the data to the database), and redirects the request to the angular route with a query var indicating the id of the transaction.

The angular controller uses $location.search() to pull the transaction id from the query var, and from there it performs a get request to the express API, which performs authentication and loads the relevant information into $scope variables to be passed to the view.